# Browser FullScreen Event listener?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

Clarifications:

1. By browser full screen I mean the browser window, NOT the DOM window.
2. I don't want a jQuery answer.
3. I really don't want to use the `setInterval()` method - I'm looking for some kind of event listener similar to `document.addEventListener('browserFullScreen', doStuff())`.

I know the dom window can be detected if fullscreen through [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) - but this is for true fullscreen - i.e. F11. I need a way of detecting whether when a user would drag a browser window around a screen then "snap" it to the top of the screen which then causes the browser window to go to full screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your use case for this?

Comment: Who downvoted? Not cool. I am resizing an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one approach to take is on resize, compare the browser's outer width and height to the screen's width and height, and if both heights and widths are the same, respectively, then the browser is covering the entire screen.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const windowWidth = window.outerWidth;
    const windowHeight = window.outerHeight;
    const screenWidth = screen.width;
    const screenHeight = screen.height;

    if (windowWidth === screenWidth && windowHeight === screenHeight) {
        // browser window is covering entire screen
    }
});
```

Comment: The `resize` event doesn't trigger if the screen is "snapped" to full screen.

Comment: hmm I see what you mean, is this for a specific OS?

Comment: Ideally cross browser. but at the very least chrome and firefox. Can you confirm I'm not going insane please. I just tried `window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){console.log(event)})` in the console of this page and it triggered? I dragged the window to the top of the screen, it snapped full screen and it worked? Using chrome.

Comment: sorry, I would but I'm on OS X, I don't have that snap feature. Either way, if the resize handler works for the snap feature, then great

Comment: Appreciated none the less. Apologies if I seem really stupid on this - been a long day haha